# Get string from window in curses

Tags: python, curses

I am making a console game in python using curses **BUT** I can not find a function to get a string from the screen.

**Python**:

```
import curses

############
# Game Map #
############
gameMap = """
##########
#________#
#________#
##########
"""

gameWin = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
curses.curs_set(0)
gameWin.keypad(1)

gameWin.clear()
gameWin.addstr(gameMap)
gameWin.addstr(playerY, playerX, playerIcon)
game_over = False
while game_over == False:
    c = gameWin.getch()

    if c == curses.KEY_RIGHT ## and gameWin. some function (playerY,playerX+1) != "#":
                                       #### this line ^^^^
        playerX += 1
    gameWin.clear()
    gameWin.addstr(gameMap)
    gameWin.addstr(playerY, playerX, playerIcon)
curses.nocbreak(); gameWin.keypad(0); curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
```

As you can see I want to get the string at `playerY`, `playerX` in `gameWin`
I have tried `getstr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [`instr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.instr).

Personally, I suggest using the screen only as output and not as storage, so you'd keep an internal representation of the game board that was more suited to the logic of the game itself. But that's up to you.